# Render partial slim html template inside JS

Tags: javascript, html, slim-lang

I want to move the rendering of a partial template from my slim HTML file to the JS code as it only happens after a click on a specific element. However, the render does not work the way I want it to. It just shows in the UI:

> = render partial:'form'

instead of the rendered template.

This is my JS code:

```
$('ul.nav.nav-tabs#myTabs li').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'main-tab') {
     $('.main-window').html(" = render partial:'form'");
    }
}
```

The HTML slim looked like this (before taking out the render):

```
ul.nav.nav-tabs#myTabs role="tablist"
 li.active: a.tab#bot-tab role="tab" aria-expanded=true data-toggle="tab" href="#bot" Bot
 li: a.tab#main-tab role="tab" aria-expanded=true data-toggle="tab" href="#main" Main
span.main-window = render partial:'form'
```

The rendering part I want to move to the JS. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "HTML slim", but this looks like a pre-processed syntax that gets turned into HTML before delivery. Setting it client side is unlikely to work (Or at least, setting it with jQuery as vanilla HTML won't)

Comment: You'll need to either add conditionals in your slim code or hide/show as you want using jQuery, but after rendering everything

Comment: Yea you will need a slim-lang javascript interpreter (dont know if it exists). Or render your slim-string via ajax. Send content to script and process on server-side.

Comment: thank you all! I did it with hide/show and it works perfectly